# php script doesn't execute with ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i need your help.

i have some input with a button like this.

```
<input type="text" name="cmsperso" id="cmsperso" />
<input type="text" name="chefdequart" id="chefdequart" />
<input type="text" name="adjoint" id="adjoint" />
<button type="submit" name="perso" onClick="perso()">envoyer</button>
```

the onClick call an ajax function.

```
function perso() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "form/perso.php",
});}
```

and in my perso.php, i have this update.

```
$cnx = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" );
$db = mysql_select_db( "maincourante" );
$req = mysql_query("SELECT idops FROM ops ORDER BY idops DESC LIMIT 1");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($req);

$cmsperso = $_POST["cmsperso"];
$chefdequart = $_POST["chefdequart"];
$adjoint = $_POST["adjoint"];

$perso = utf8_decode("UPDATE `Opérations n°".$data['idops']."` SET cmsperso='$cmsperso', chefdequart='$chefdequart', adjoint='$adjoint'");

mysql_query($perso, $cnx) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
```

all is working fine exept the update. In phpmyadmin none of the value is update.

please help

Comment: Where is the insert query to the database?

Comment: what about all the mysql connections and queries, do you have it as well?

Comment: i don't have insert query, just update query in this script. and i have the mysql connection.

Comment: i try to replace my update query to an insert query and it doesn't work too

Comment: You should show more context around your query (like where you actually make the query).  Also, are you getting a specific MySQL error back?  You also realize that your update query is going to change ALL rows in the table to those values?

Comment: It doesn't looks like the ajax request is posting any data at all by the looks of the code?

Comment: try wrapping fields with (``) $perso = utf8_decode("UPDATE `Opérations n°1` SET `cmsperso`='$cmsperso', `chefdequart`='$chefdequart', `adjoint`='$adjoint'");

Comment: is this `Opérations n°1` your table name?

Comment: i don't have specific error in firebug.

Comment: operation n°1 is my table name ! yep

Comment: @user1825668 Is that your actual JS for the AJAX request? You're not passing any data.

Answer (score 1):

you are not sending the variable values in your post,

```
function perso() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "form/perso.php",
});}
```

need to add the variable and value to this call like:

```
function perso() {
$.post("form/perso.php", { adjoint: $("#adjoint").val(), cmsperso: $("#cmsperso").val(), chefdequart: $("#chefdequart").val() } );
});}
```

also take a look at [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for managing your data objects as your query can be injected into

finaly it seems you have no `where` clause, this means that ALL lines in your table will be updated which probably not what you were after.

another think i would consider is naming you table something simpler than it is now having spaces and special charaters in there is asking for trouble.

Comment: ok that solves the actual values, what about the `where` clause?

Comment: i don't need to specify where clause cause i have just one id

Comment: then i suggest some simple debugging ... print out the sql query before you try to execute it and see what it is exactly

Comment: ok print return this.

UPDATE `Op�rations n�1` SET cmsperso='', chefdequart='', adjoint=''

Comment: ok this should tell you that the problem is you are not senting the variables at all to the script. ill update my answer

Comment: it was not sent because you did not send it, the post command you created dosent know which form it came from or what variables it has in it, you have to specify the data you want to send

Comment: i have try to send via ajax and it return me

POST http://localhost/mainCouranteOperation/form/perso.php 200 OK 51ms 

UPDATE `Op�rations n�1` SET cmsperso='zrgzgz', chefdequart='jjfkdh,d', adjoint='zegzeg'

POST http://localhost/mainCouranteOperation/form/perso.php 200 OK 144ms 

UPDATE `Op�rations n�1` SET cmsperso='', chefdequart='', adjoint=''

and no data will update

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `Opérations n°".$data['idops']."` is the correct table you are trying to update?

Comment: Can you open up phpMyAdmin and run your sql query in there? Just fill in the variables with some test placeholders and see if it udpates there.

Just paste the below in and see if it udpates.
UPDATE `Opérations n°".$data['idops']."` SET cmsperso='test', chefdequart='test2', adjoint='test3'

Comment: If you haven't tried printing out the variables that you post then try that and make sure your variables are correct. You could also try editing: mysql_query($perso, $cnx) or die(mysql_error()); to: mysql_query($perso) or die(mysql_error());

Since you didn't use ,$cnx in your first query.

Answer (score 0):

good morning,

i think, i partially resolve my problem

this is my code

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
var xhr2 = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        xhr2 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e) {
        xhr2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    } 
    else {
      xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  } 
  else {
    alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
    return null;
  }
  return xhr2;
}

/* ressources */
function perso() {
  $.post("form/perso.php", { 
    cmsperso: $("#cmsperso").val(), 
    chefdequart: $("#chefdequart").val(),
    adjoint: $("#adjoint").val()
  });

  var xhr2 = getXMLHttpRequest();

  xhr2.open("POST", "form/perso.php", false);
}
```

and this return in firebug

[image: firebug 302 found]

any idea?